# Cannot output to client

Tags: java, sockets, networking

I close the connection to any sockets after 2 clients are connected, it works correctly but doesn't print the max players connected message

```
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),true);
connectedClients++;
if (connectedClients < maxPlayers) {
    MortgageRunnable m = new MortgageRunnable(clientSocket);
    System.out.println("New player has connected!");
    new Thread(m).start();
} else {
    out.println("Connection unsuccessful, Max players connected");
    clientSocket.close();
}
```

Comment: You need to close the `PrintWriter`, not the socket, and you alos need to be aware that `PrintWriter` swallows exceptions.

Comment: What do you mean by swallow exceptions?

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks fine for writing to the client. Here's a simpler version that accepts a single connection and writes "test" to the client.

```
ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(1234);
Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(), true);
out.println("test");
```

And here's output using `telnet` as a client:

```
~ $ telnet localhost 1234
Trying ::1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
test
Connection closed by foreign host.
~ $
```

You might be running into an issue because you're calling [`close()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#close--) right after `out.println()` such that the close happens prior to I/O finishing. You could try wrapping `close()` in a `try-catch` to see if any exceptions are thrown, like this:

```
try {
    clientSocket.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: I'll try it and get back to you